# Numpy exp function

Tags: python, numpy, exponential

Why when I write expX = s0 * np.exp(XY), I end up with the following error ? Length of passed values is 1440, index implies 1.
I want the value S0 to be multiply by the first XY and the result to become the next S0 so that it can be multiply by the next XY, and so on on the 1440 value.

Thanks

```
  T = 1                               #len(index_future)
  N = 1440                            #number of time steps (min in 
  1 day)
  dt = T / N                          #time steps
  mu = returns_log.mean(axis= 0)/N    #mean return  
  t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
  #print(mu)
  #sys.exit()
  sigma = returns_log.std(axis= 0)    #total vol
  #print(sigma)
  #S0 = close.tail(1)                  #last return observed
  S0 = close['ETHJPY'].sample()
  #print (S0)
  #sys.exit()
  dt = sigma/np.sqrt(N)               #local volatility
  print(dt)


  W = np.cumsum(d[0])*np.sqrt(dt[0])  
  print(W)
  np.savetxt("checkkk.csv", W, delimiter=",")
  #sys.exit()                 
  Y= (sigma[0]*W)                        #random shocks

  X = (mu[0] - 0.5 * sigma[0]**2) * t       #drift

  XY = sum(X,Y).T#[np.newaxis]                         #drift + random shocks

  #expX = np.exp(XY['ETHJPY'])
  expX = s0 * np.exp(XY)
```

Comment: What's the error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Sorry, I though it was clear enough. I wrote the error the error is : "Length of passed values is 1440, index implies 1"

Comment: That's not clear enough, we don't know where and we don't know what. Provide a [mcve].